# Error: Bad Request - Invalid image, could not read metadata from Sanity image upload in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I have an input type file, and whenever that file changes I will update the profile picture. However the console shows this error: `Error: Bad Request - Invalid image, could not read metadata`. Here is my code (simplified):

```
const updateProfilePicture = (file) => {
const pfpHTML = document.querySelector('#pfp');
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function () {
  const base64Image = reader.result

  pfpHTML.src = base64Image

  client.assets.upload('image', new File([base64Image], file.name, { type: file.type })).
    then(response => {
      const imageAssetId = response._id;
      console.log(response);

      client.patch(data._id)
        .set({ profilePicture: { _type: 'image', asset: { _ref: imageAssetId } } })
        .commit()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Profile picture updated successfully!')
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error updating profile picture:', error)
        })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error)
    })
}
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

 return (
   <img src="" id="pfp-image" alt="" />
   <FormControl className="mt-3">
      <FormLabel>Profile Picture:</FormLabel>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => updateProfilePicture(e.target.files[0])} />
   </FormControl>
 )
```